# AWS ELB and GoDaddy Domain working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I have registered a domain in goDaddy.com and want the traffic to be sent to AWS route53. I have a ELB created I did the following steps

1. In Route 53, created a HostedZone for my godaddy domain name which in turn gave me a NS record with 4 amazon DNS server names and an SOA record.
2. Created a new "A" record with just the naked domain and Aliased it with Elastic LB
3. In godaddy , in DNS management, If I use the ELB DNS name for "A" record, I get an error "Enter a valid IP address" where as if I give the EC2 public IP address for "A" record  , I can see the index page . I have still not given the 4 NS record DNS server names in godaddy.

***Questions*** :

1. How do I use ELB instead of using EC2 Public IP.
2. If I use the NS values, does that means the domain is ported to AWS Route53 and I will be charged every month at AWS? If I use the EC2 IP address only in goDaddy ,then I will not be charged by AWS ?

Hope I am clear on my question, if not please let me know I can explain further

Comment: Will you use AWS or GoDaddy to manage DNS records?  From your question it seems you are creating records on both.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all AWS ELB does not provide a A record with an IP address and instead it provides a CName. Unfortunately a CName cannot be mapped to a naked domain in DNS configurations and as a work around, AWS provides an Alias for A record.

However using Godaddy DNS, Alias to AWS resources such as ELB is not possible which limits using naked domain mappings to ELB. Therefore you need to delegate DNS management to Route53 hosted zone(Or atleast for the naked domain) having the name server forwarding which cost you around $0.5 per hosted zone month for the first 25 hosted zones.

Since an IP address is available for an EC2, if you directly point an A record in Godaddy, it won't cost for DNS at AWS.

Comment: It helped.Thanks.

Comment: In godaddy, in the DNS management I have "A" record with name "@" with my EC2 IP address.So if I give example.com ( just my naked domain name ) it will give show my index.html page in browser. How does the www.example.com also gives my index.html page ? Is it because I have the Type CNAME , Name as "www" , value as "@"  ?