# Wix + GoDaddy domain + AWS ELB for subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, aws-elb

I have a marketing website on wix with domain registered with godaddy, I've added a subdomain pointing to my EC2 IP for my app facing server, which works fine. Now I want to add a load balancer in front of that EC2 instance, however I cannot set the ELB A record in GoDaddy. Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44935080/aws-elb-and-godaddy-domain-working#:%7E:text=However%20using%20Godaddy%20DNS%2C%20Alias%20to%20AWS%20resources,zone%20month%20for%20the%20first%2025%20hosted%20zones.) I created a hosted zone but if I change the name server I'll loose access to my wix website.

I want only the subdomain to point to my ELB while the main domain continues to point to the wix website, - do I need to change the name servers in GD to point to the aws hosted zone and then in the hosted zone map my main domain to the wix website and the subdomain to the elb? Do I need to move my domain registration to route 53 altogether?

What is the most recommended setup for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, writing for future help.

You need a hosted zone on route 53 pointing to the ELB, this gives you name servers. In GoDaddy *add* those name servers with your subdomain, keeping the existing name servers intact :)